# Android: requestFocus() isn't characters from soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment, android-softkeyboard

In an Activity say `MainActivity`, i have programatically added a Fragment say `Fragment_1`

This `Fragment_1` has a layout which contains an `EditText`. When i start showing this `Fragment_1`, the `EditText` gets focused but the `soft keyboard` is not openned

So i click on the `EditText` to open the `keyboard`, `type some text` and `click done button`, which must replace `Fragment_1` with `Fragment_2` which also contains an `EditText`.

But this `EditText` in `Fragment_2` is not `focused`, but the `keyboard` is still `open` (may be because of the last `Fragment_1`)

so i added this for `Fragment_2`

```
EditText.requestFocus();
```

the focus is there and the keyboard is open, but the `EditText` is not getting populated by the Key Characters i am clicking.

Why is it so??

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide keyboard for first edit text on first fragment

```
private InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
EditText.clearFocus();
mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and than you should request focus and show keyboard for second edit text:

```
EditText.requestFocus();
mInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(EditText, 0);
```

Comment: its not working. The Soft keyboard is not showing up even after clicking the EditText. on which i invoked requestFocus();

Comment: its just getting the focus. but the soft keyboard is not opening. even after clicking the editText

Answer (score 0):

The input method manager ignores keyboard requests unless the `EditText` and the Window it’s in both have focus. So upon entering an `Activity` / `Dialog`, you need to wait until focus has settled down before you request the keyboard. You can do this by calling the `InputMethodManager` service in an `OnFocusChangeListener`, but Views can get focus before the Window itself does, so you have to wait for Window focus. There is no way that you can find to add an `OnFocusChangeListener` on the Window object itself, but listening for View focus and posting a Runnable seems to work.

[Please look at a beautiful analysis here](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-edittext-receives-focus/)